# How do I use the phrase "in a row"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I went hiking to enjoy autumn leaves last Saturday, Saturday before last and also Saturday three weeks ago.

If I add "in a row" to this sentence, what sentence can I make?

> I went hiking on three Saturdays in a row.

This is the only sentence I can make, but it doesn't sound right to me. This sentence also doesn't say which Saturday I went. If I put all the information in one or two sentences, how should I say it? This is for conversation.

Comment: It probably doesn't sound right because you should drop the preposition _on_: ***I went hiking three Saturdays in a row***. An alternative would be: ***I went hiking on Saturdays three weeks in a row***.

Comment: @J.R. I like the sentence better without *on*, too!  But I wouldn't go so far as to say they **should** drop the preposition, myself.  I think it's okay having it there.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers and comments.  I really learned a lot from these.  I think I want to stick to the past tense here, which is easier for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.
"I went hiking on three Saturdays in a row" is a correct sentence, but doesn't specify how long ago those hikes were.

If you want to add that information, you could use

> I went hiking on the last three Saturdays

or:

> I went hiking on each of the last three Saturdays

Comment: Actually I don't think that you can use both. *I went hiking on the last three Saturdays* is perfectly acceptable and gets across the point of the time frame. And as you said, *I went hiking three Saturdays in a row* is also correct, but doesn't specify time frame. I think this answer is good and correct except for advocating that you can use both in the same sentence, which sounds wrong to me. Since you've already specified the last 3 Saturdays, *in a row* is redundant and seems to have some other meaning... Like "I walked in straight rows while I hiked" or something.

Comment: @WendiKidd I believe you'Re right, so I edited my post. Do you think, "in a row" would be valid in the second example?

Comment: No, I think you need to choose either *in a row* or *on the last three Saturdays*. *In a row* is unneeded, because you already said *the last three*; we know logically that they are *in a row* already :) I made one tiny edit to add a missing word, and I've upvoted now! :)

Comment: You can also say "I have gone hiking the last three Saturdays in a row."

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the present perfect construction to indicate a sequence of events that is ongoing:

> I have gone hiking three Saturdays in a row.

Because it is an ongoing sequence, the only three Saturdays which can qualify are the three most recent ones.

There is still some ambiguity here (which would normally be mitigated by vocal intonation) as to whether this is an "unspecified time in the past" use of the past perfect, or an "ongoing sequence" use, but I believe the default reading would be that it is an ongoing sequence.

Nevertheless, if you really want to use "in a row" and still remove the ambiguity completely, you can add an explicit time reference:

> I have gone hiking three Saturdays in a row now.

The addition of "now" at the end makes it absolutely clear that this is an ongoing sequence of events.